# Increase aws session token expiration time

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2, boto3, multi-factor-authentication

I am using a python script that login to AWS account with an IAM user and MFA (multi-factor authentication) enabled. The script runs continuously and does some operations (IoT, fetching data from devices etc etc).

As mentioned, the account needs an MFA code while starting the script, and it does perfectly. But the problem is script fails after 36 hours because the token expires.
Can we increase the session token expiration time or automate this task not to ask MFA code again and again?

Comment: No. The point of MFA is literally to stop programmatic access to your account.

Comment: Don't we have something which generates the OTP (one time password) automatic and authenticate before 36Hours? Basically saying script should not stop after 36 Hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't extend the expiration, but you can circumvent the protections (at your own risk). In principle, you can store the MFA secret used to generate TOTP codes (e.g., what QR setup codes provide) and have your script generate OTP codes to perform MFA challenges automatically. For example, using the [PyOTP](https://pyauth.github.io/pyotp/) library. Of course, if your MFA requirements require more than TOTP (like enforced biometrics or physical touch keys) then this won't work.

But it would probably be easier to just setup a solution that avoids the need for MFA to begin with. For example, deploy your script to run on an EC2 instance with an instance role with necessary permissions or create an IAM user that does not have MFA requirements.

Comment: I require only TOTP (No bio-metrics or physical touch) . What do you mean by `you can store the MFA secret used to generate TOTP codes? `

Comment: @OneTouchForHeight when you first setup MFA, you are provided with a secret that is used to generate TOTPs. For example, most services present this to users as a QR code that authenticator apps can translate into the secret key. Check out the [PyOTP docs](https://pyauth.github.io/pyotp/#working-example) which give a pretty good explanation of what the secret is and how to use it.

Comment: Thanks I found [this](https://www.nsoftware.com/kb/articles/awstotp.rst) useful. I will the follow the instructions and code to verify.

Comment: I successfully generated same totp as authenticate APP using pytop.TOTP('secretkey_from_MFA_QR_code') and script no longer require to input manually OTP. It is automatic.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not, the value can range from 900 seconds (15 minutes) to 129600 seconds (36 hours). If you are using root user credentials, then the range is from 900 seconds (15 minutes) to 3600 seconds (1 hour).